# равнозначны ли формулы?

Tags: математика

секретная экспонента Генерации ключей RSA вычисляется так:

**Ф(N)** - значение функции Эйлера

**d*e=1(modФ(N))**

это равнозначно?

**d*e=1+Ф(N)**

Comment: я признаться недопонимаю как считают, ориентируюсь этого примера: 3*7=1(modФ(20)) -> 21=1(modФ(20)) - вот я и предположил

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нет, эти два выражения неравнозначны. Первое означает, что произведение de в остатке от деления на Ф(N) даёт 1. То есть, по определению остатка,

de = 1 + k Ф(N),

где k — некоторое целое число.

Второе же выражение — это частный случай, когда k=1. То есть, из второго следует первое, но не наоборот.